# Copy view controller from one project to another

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, copy

I am working on project X. I needed to add component Y to the project. So I go and create component Y as a separate project, say Project W. Now I need to copy Project W into Project X as component Y. How do I do that? I don't mind copying one piece at a time such as: copy ViewControllers in storyboard manually, and then copy the classes manually. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. You can just drag files (view controllers or anything else) from one project into the navigator pane of another. You can also copy and paste view controller scenes in the storyboard. Are you looking for something different?

Comment: No. The scene part is not working for copy and paste between projects. So looks like I have to redo it by hand.

Comment: I don't know why that's not working for you, I've done it many times. How are you trying o do it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the ViewController or storyboard object, select the top bar so you're selecting the whole thing, and then hit COMMAND + C to copy.

Then go to your other project, and open up Storyboard, and place your cursor down onto the open field, and hit COMMAND + V to paste it.

Typically you then have to zoom out on storyboard scene to see it, as for some reason it'll place it down all cattywampus.  However, you'll see the files appear in your list of scenes (middle or left panel).

Comment: >>> cattywampus